# Vocabularies with terms on a view

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I need to create a page with listed vocabularies and terms related to it in 3 columns.

```
Vocabulary 1       Vocabulary 2     Vocabulary 3
Term 1             Term 4            Term 7
Term 2             Term 5            Term 8
Term 3             Term 6            Term 9
```

If it's possible, I'd like to accomplish that by configuring a view. I'm not very good with custom code.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Create 3 view blocks, one for each Vocab, place blocks on a page. Sprinkle some CSS to make them [inline](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_inline-block.asp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunatelly for Drupal 8 @No Sssweat's solution of creating 3 seperate views (blocks) is the ONLY possible solution using views at the moment.  Then you can put them in region of your liking and with css can display them one next to the other (inline).

When [Taxonomy vocabulary data not available as views fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2658956) is not an issue anymore you will be able to do it with just 1 view and grouping terms by vocabulary name.

Otherwise another solution would be to make your own custom module that gathers and displays the vocabulary terms.

Comment: Thanks to @No Ssweat and you! Just did it following your suggested method and also used "insert_view" module to place it in basic page body.